# Firebase Nuxt.js - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'collection')

Tags: firebase, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm using Nuxt.js and I want to add my data on Firebase. When I click add button, it returns an error
Error is :

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'collection')

this is my add method:

```
addList(value) {

  
  try {
    this.$fire.firestore.collection('toDoList').doc('id123').set({
    name: value.name,
    job:value.job
  })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
  

}
```

I added firebase library in my project

how can I solve this problem ?

full error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'collection')
at VueComponent.addList (index.vue?6ced:43:1)
at invokeWithErrorHandling (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3015:1)
at VueComponent.invoker (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1813:1)
at invokeWithErrorHandling (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3015:1)
at Vue.$emit (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3714:1)
at VueComponent.sendData (ToDoForm.vue?1e1a:41:1)
at click (ToDoForm.vue?dbf7:69:1)
at invokeWithErrorHandling (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3015:1)
at HTMLButtonElement.invoker (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1813:1)
at original_1._wrapper (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:7458:1)
```

Comment: So, so you have something in `this.$fire.firestore`?

Comment: yes, I don't know why this error exists

Comment: What do you have there? Can you give us a bit more debugging material?

Comment: So, do you have something in `this.$fire.firestore`?